# Trait to implement only on "castable" types

Tags: rust

When I have following enum:

```
#[repr(u8)]
enum Animal {
   Cat,
   Dog,
   Mouse,
}
```

It is possible to cast it to `u8` simply with

```
let n = Animal::Cat as u8
```

Now, I would like to implement trait `ToU8` with a single function:

```
trait ToU8 {
    fn to_u8(self) -> u8 { self as u8 }
}
```

The above code of course throws an error, because `as` might not work for all types.
Is there any way to make this work? How can I communicate to the compiler that `Self` is going to work with `as`?

Comment: That's not possible. Neither is it desirable, you're far better off implementing `Into` for this. Just one of the reasons: Add a value (e.g. `Cat { age: u8 }`) to one of the variants, the `as` code will still work, but bath in the hilarity that ensues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You need to leave the method in the trait without default implementation, and implement it for the types you want.

There were some RFCs allowing you to do that, e.g. [#3046](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3046), but none of them were accepted.